# "ambiguous call to overloaded function" when using variadic templates in VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2013, variadic-templates

Given the following code:

```
        template <typename T>
        bool TryQueryInterface(
            IUnknown* in_toQuery,
            REFIID riid,
            void **ppvObject,
            ComObject* in_parent,
            HRESULT out_result)
        {
            if (InterfaceProperties<T>::GetIID() == riid)
            {
                void *underlying;
                HRESULT result = in_toQuery->QueryInterface(riid, &underlying);
                if (SUCCEEDED(result))
                {
                    *ppvObject = new typename InterfaceProperties<T>::WrapperClass(
                        *this,
                        (T*)underlying,
                        in_parent);
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        template <typename T, typename... Interfaces>
        bool TryQueryInterfaces(
            IUnknown* in_toQuery,
            REFIID riid,
            void **ppvObject,
            ComObject* in_parent,
            HRESULT out_result)
        {
            return TryQueryInterface<T>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result) ||
                   TryQueryInterfaces<Interfaces...>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
        }

        template <typename T>
        bool TryQueryInterfaces(
            IUnknown* in_toQuery,
            REFIID riid,
            void **ppvObject,
            ComObject* in_parent,
            HRESULT out_result)
        {
            return TryQueryInterface<T>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
        }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    error C2668: 'TryQueryInterfaces' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
TryQueryInterfaces<ITrusteeGroupAdmin>(IUnknown *,const IID &,void **,ComObject *,HRESULT)'
 or       TryQueryInterfaces<ITrusteeGroupAdmin,>(IUnknown *,const IID &,void **,ComObject *,HRESULT)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(IUnknown *, const IID, void **, ComObject *, HRESULT)'
see reference to function template instantiation 'bool TryQueryInterfaces<ITrusteeAdmin,ITrusteeGroupAdmin>(IUnknown *,const IID &,void **,ComObject *,HRESULT)' being compiled
```

What am I missing here? How do I construct an unambiguous base case for the recursion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ambiguous because the parameter pack `Interfaces...` could be empty. Make sure that you take at least one argument plus a number of additional (possibly zero) parameters. Change the second method to:

```
template <typename T, typename Interface, typename... Interfaces>
bool TryQueryInterfaces(
    IUnknown* in_toQuery,
    REFIID riid,
    void **ppvObject,
    ComObject* in_parent,
    HRESULT out_result)
{
    return TryQueryInterface<T>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result) ||
           TryQueryInterfaces<Interface, Interfaces...>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use `enable_if` to only enable the `TryQueryInterfaces` implementation taking a parameter pack when the pack is not empty. You should also rearrange the two `TryQueryInterfaces` implementations so that the terminal case, handling the single template parameter, is above the other one. This allows name lookup within the parameter pack version to succeed.

This also allows you to get rid of the `TryQueryInterface` implementation.

```
template<typename T>
bool TryQueryInterfaces(IUnknown* in_toQuery,
                        REFIID riid,
                        void **ppvObject,
                        ComObject* in_parent,
                        HRESULT out_result)
{
    // query single interface here
}

template<typename T, typename... Interfaces>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Interfaces) != 0, bool>::type
 TryQueryInterfaces(IUnknown* in_toQuery,
                    REFIID riid,
                    void **ppvObject,
                    ComObject* in_parent,
                    HRESULT out_result)
{
    return TryQueryInterfaces<T>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result) || 
           TryQueryInterfaces<Interfaces...>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d115df7b13034b5)

Answer (score 3):

```
 template <typename T>
 void foo();
```

and

```
 template <typename T, template ...R>
 void foo();
```

both match `foo<X>();`

To make some difference use two types:

```
 template <typename T1, typename T2, template ...R>
 void foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

Overloading functions with variadic templates is a little bit different than with regular templates.

You can overload:

```
void foo()
{
}
```

and

```
template <typename Arg1, typename ...Args>
void foo()
{
}
```

but not

```
template <typename Arg1>
void foo()
{
}
```

and

```
template <typename Arg1, typename ...Args>
void foo()
{
}
```

because there is no way to disambiguate which function to call when there is one argument.

In your case, you can use a helper class to handle the calls.

```
// Forward declaration of the helper class and its template arguments.
template <typename ...Types> struct TryQueryInterfacesHelper;

// helper class with just one argument.
template <typename T>
struct TryQueryInterfacesHelper<T>
{
   bool operator()(IUnknown* in_toQuery,
                   REFIID riid,
                   void **ppvObject,
                   ComObject* in_parent,
                   HRESULT out_result)
   {
      return TryQueryInterface<T>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
   }
};

// helper class with more than one argument.
template <typename T, typename ...Interfaces>
struct TryQueryInterfacesHelper<T, Interfaces...>
{
   bool operator()(IUnknown* in_toQuery,
                   REFIID riid,
                   void **ppvObject,
                   ComObject* in_parent,
                   HRESULT out_result)
   {
      return TryQueryInterface<T>(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result) ||
         TryQueryInterfacesHelper<Interfaces...>()(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
   }
};

template <typename... Interfaces>
bool TryQueryInterfaces(
      IUnknown* in_toQuery,
      REFIID riid,
      void **ppvObject,
      ComObject* in_parent,
      HRESULT out_result)
{
   // Implement the function using the helper class.
   return TryQueryInterfacesHelper<Interfaces...>()(in_toQuery, riid, ppvObject, in_parent, out_result);
}
```

Here's an example program that tests the idea with a simpler class and function.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class ...Types> struct X;

template <class T>
struct X<T>
{
   void operator()(){std::cout << "Came to X<T>\n";}
};

template <class T, class ...Types>
struct X<T, Types...> 
{
   void operator()(){std::cout << "Came to X<T, Types...>\n"; X<Types...>()();}
};

template <class ...Types>
void foo()
{
   X<Types...>()();
}

int main()
{
   foo<int>();
   foo<int, double>();
   foo<int, double, char>();
}
```

Output:

```
Came to X<T>
Came to X<T, Types...>
Came to X<T>
Came to X<T, Types...>
Came to X<T, Types...>
Came to X<T>
```